# Input search form shows rounded border on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: html, css

I have a search form that I coded to only include a border-bottom styling. On desktop it appears as I want it to (second photo), but on mobile it's showing a rounded border (first photo). I'm using Chrome on both desktop and iOS mobile...

[image]
[image]

```css
.search-bar {
  height: 60px;
  padding:1em;
  outline: none;
}

#search {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Linux Libertine;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Linux Libertine, times;
  color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
   <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter a keyword" class="keyword" />
</div>
```

Comment: set the appearance to none https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;` is generally the fix for ios.

Comment: beautiful, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

but what mobile are you using? Iphone or android? You see, chrome on iphone actually uses safari to render stuff (in a sense). Apple has round buttons, where as we generally have squared ones. Just use `border-radius:0;` to fix.
You may also be looking for `-webkit-appearance: none;` for iphones. I believe that is also a part of the apple experience.

So:

```
#search {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Linux Libertine;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```